# The 'hum' of conversation

Tags: word-choice

This is a well worn phrase I'm trying to avoid in my writing. I'm looking for another word to replace 'hum', which I take to mean the background noise resulting from people talking. I came up with 'murmur', but ideally, I'd like a word that suggests a deep pitch. You see, I'm writing about a group of men, and in my head, I compare the sound of their voices to sounds stones would make as they bounce off each other while being carried along by a river. 'Trundle'? I thought 'gravel', but then, I plan to use that word a short distance away, and I *hate* clumsy repeats.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about a `grumble` ? But the again, it can also mean a complaint. So it would depend on what they are talking about.

Comment: Does it have to be a single word? I find your description quite a nice mental image, one that i haven't heared before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“A rumble of men's voices” might be an appropriate phrase, using *[rumble](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rumble#Noun)*'s sense  “A low, heavy, continuous sound, such as that of thunder or a hungry stomach”.

Comment: Very good! This is the word I ended up using. It was the perfect fit, but I enjoyed the other suggestions that turned up.

Answer (score 7):

OP could go with ***murmur***, but I and most other Anglophones [tend to use ***buzz***...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hum%20of%20conversation,buzz%20of%20conversation,murmur%20of%20conversation&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

On the other hand, since OP wants a word evocative of running water, it's worth noting...

> *babbling brook* [44,500 instances in Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22killing%20streak%22%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22babbling%20brook%22&tbm=bks)
>    ***babble*** of conversation [24,900 instances](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22killing%20streak%22%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22babble%20of%20conversation%22&tbm=bks)

Answer (score 2):

[Burble](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burble)

> To make the quiet sound of water moving over rocks

also [purl](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/purl)

> To flow or ripple with a murmuring sound.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe the noise as ***lithophonic*** *drone* or *hum* or *noise*.

A [lithophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithophone) is a musical instrument consisting of a rock or pieces of rock which are struck to produce musical notes.

Answer (score 1):

Amid the chatter, chitchat, jabbering, yammering, clacking, yakking, ...

Non-onomatopoeic 'group of men': shooting the breeze, chewing the fat

Answer (score 1):

I have always described it as a "din".
The room was filled with a din of conversation.
If you're at a busy bar with friends, you must compete with the din in the room in order to hold a conversation.
In your case I might say something like, "The room was filled with the baritone din of conversation."

[image]